# Trying to load certain form if user is authenticated and preload all the information in the database with the user credentials

Tags: python, django, forms, user-input

Trying to load certain form if a user is authenticated and preload all the information in the database but I get this error, most probably something is wrong in forms.py but the idea is that if the user is authenticated they should not go through the process of entering their name and email, they would just have to send the message. It currently works like a charm for non registered users but I never did something like this before for the registered users so I am stuck.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Message

class NonAuthMessage(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = "__all__"

class AuthMessage(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = user.request.username
        self.email = user.request.email

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ["message"]
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Message(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    message = models.TextField(max_length=3000)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_posted',]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Message
from .forms import NonAuthMessage, AuthMessage

def contact(request):

    formAuth = AuthMessage()
    formNonAuth = NonAuthMessage()
    mess = Message.objects.all()

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = AuthMessage(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('contact')
                messages.success(request, 'Message sent to Alex!')
    else:
        if request.method =="POST":
            form = NonAuthMessage(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('contact')
                messages.success(request, 'Message sent to Alex!')

    context = {'formAuth': formAuth, 'formNonAuth': formNonAuth, 'mess': mess}

    return render(request, 'contact/contact.html', context)
```

**contact.html**

```
{% extends 'personal/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Contact Alex</legend>
                    {{formAuth | crispy}} <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Send</button>
                    </div>
            </fieldset>
</form>
{% else %}
<form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Contact Alex</legend>
                    {{formNonAuth | crispy}} <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Send</button>
                    </div>
            </fieldset>
</form>
{% endif %}

           <!-- TESTING -->
           {% for message in mess %}
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3 >{{message.email}}</h3> 
                    {{message.date_posted}}<hr>
                    <p>
                    {{message.message|truncatewords:"25"}} 
                    </p>
              </div>
              {% endfor %}


{% endblock content %}
```

***And the error message that I get is:***

NameError at /contact/;
name 'user' is not defined

**Traceback:**

views.py: 
`formAuth = AuthMessage()` 
forms.py:

```
self.name = user.request.username
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put needed user info directly in view instead of in form:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AuthMessage(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            authmess = form.save(commit=False)
            authmess.name = request.user.first_name
            authmess.email = request.user.email
            authmess.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Message sent to Alex!') 
            return redirect('contact')
```